# How to group product variations in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

In Conversions > Product Performance, Analytics shows individual variations as separate products.

Example: the same product but in different sizes gets treated as a different "product", like this:

[image]

Do you know how you can group these together so when you're looking at Product Performance you can see actual product performance (rather than variation performance).

I've tried various primary and secondary dimensions but can't find it.

It's good to see which styles are selling well and their conversion rates as a the product page for all it's variation options.